# Find the cluster points of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Given the set $A=[a,b)$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a< b$, write the set of ALL cluster points of A.

Okay so i understand the definition of a cluster point, knowing that for any $I=\{x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon\}$ for $\epsilon>0$ there must be infinitely many points in the interval, but how do I use this to find the set of cluster points for $A$? Thanks

Comment: Is there a point of $A$ which _isn't_ a cluster point (of $A$)?

Comment: @Arthur I think a and b are both cluster points, but im not sure about the numbers between them?

Comment: If you pick a number $c$ between the two, and you look at the interval $(c-\epsilon, c+\epsilon)$, how many elements of $A$ are in that interval?

Comment: infinite, so the set of cluster points will be A=[a,b]?

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$